# tastypie: filter many to many tables with multiple, ANDed values

Tags: django, filter, tastypie, relation, m2m

I have two tables (Movie and Genre) that are connected with a many to many relation using a crosstable (MovieGenre).

My models.py file looks like this:

```
class Genre( models.Model ):

    sName = models.CharField( max_length=176)
    [ .. ]

class Movie( models.Model ):

    sTitle = models.CharField( max_length=176)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField( Genre )
    [ .. ]

class MovieGenre( models.Model ):

    idMovie = models.ForeignKey( Movie )
    idGenre = models.ForeignKey( Genre )
```

I want to use tastypie to filter all movies of certain genres. E.g. show me all movies that are of genre Action, Thriller and SciFi.

My api.py looks like this:

```
class GenreResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Genre.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'genre'
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False
        excludes = ['dtCreated', 'dtModified' ]
        authorization= Authorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        filtering = {
            "id" : ALL,
        }


class MovieResource(ModelResource):
    genre = fields.ManyToManyField( 'app.api.GenreResource', 'genre', full=True )
    class Meta:
        queryset = Movie.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'movie'
        authorization= Authorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False
        excludes = ['dtCreated', 'dtModified' ]
        filtering = {
            "sTitle" : ALL,
            "genre" : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

My test data:
Two movies (with genre ids)
Matrix (1 & 3 )
Blade Runner (1 & 2 )

First I make a query on the title, as expected below query returns 1 result (namely Matrix):

```
   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/movie/?format=json&sTitle__icontains=a&sTitle__icontains=x
```

However, I get three results with the URL that should query the related genre table (two times Matrix and once Blade Runner) with this query:

```
    http://localhost:8000/api/v1/movie/?format=json&genre__id__in=3&genre__id__in=1
```

I would expect to get back only Matrix

I also tried to override apply_filters like so:

```
def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
    oList = super(ModelResource, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)
    loQ = [Q(**{'sTitle__icontains': 'a'}), Q(**{'sTitle__icontains': 'x'})]
    # works as intended: one result
    loQ = [Q(**{'genre__id__in': '3'}) ]
    # results in one result (Matrix)

    loQ = [Q(**{'genre__id__in': '1'}), Q(**{'genre__id__in': '3'}) ]
    # results in no results!

    loQ = [Q(**{'genre__id__in': [ 1, 3]}) ]
    # results in two results Matrix and Blade Runner which is OK since obviously ORed
    oFilter = reduce( operator.and_, loQ )
    oList = oList.filter( oFilter ).distinct()
    return oList
```

Any idea to make this work?

Thanks for any idea...

Comment: I'm unsure why you complicated the queries so much in your `apply_filters` method. For example, instead of something like: `loQ = [Q(**{'sTitle__icontains': 'a'}), Q(**{'sTitle__icontains': 'x'})]` you can do the same thing with this `oList = oList.filter(sTitle__icontains='a', sTitle__icontains='x').distinct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/movie/?format=json&genre__id=3&genre__id=1`

If I understand correctly, using `__in` that way would be like saying `genre__id__in=[1, 3]`.

Comment: I'd have to agree. When using `__in` it will return any result that contains an id in that list as demonstrated in the third `apply_filters` example given. Alternatives to @msc's solution could also be to use `genre__id__exact` or `genre__pk`.

Comment: genre__id=1 is same with genre__id__exact=1.

Comment: Yep, was just providing alternative syntax. Technically I should have said `genre__pk__exact` as well ;)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, using genre__id, genre__id__exact did the trick for the URL. Great! One problem is still there however, if I want to create the filter with q objects I still get no result when ANDing two "genre__id" objects like in the above example... any idea why?

Comment: One thing that works is to chain filters like: oList = oList.filter( oFilter_1 ).filter( oFilter_2 )... but this somehow smells

Comment: It may smell, but it is a valid way to AND fields in querysets. Just make sure that if you use Q, you pay attention to ordering. Also `If you provide multiple Q object arguments to a lookup function, the arguments will be “AND”ed together.`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects